# Using of activity indicator in second viewController to load lot of data in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I use activity indicator in second view controller to let data to be complete load
first VC

```
- (IBAction)btnOpenHTML:(id)sender {

RecievVC *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecievVC"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:lblName.text forKey:@"lblname"];
//........Lots of Data........(then in the end of 1st VC)........//


obj.dicData = dict;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:true];
}
@end
```

the 2nd VC Code after viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


[self->webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:true];
[self->webView loadHTMLString:[self getHTMLStirng] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
-(NSString *)getHTMLStirng {

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resumeT" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *strHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if (self.dicData) {

    strHTML = [strHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#NAME" withString:[_dicData valueForKey:@"lblname"]];
//...............Lots of Data......Then at the end of 2nd VC............//

    }return strHTML;
}
```

what I main by lots of data, it's around 150 of keys and value have to be send from 1st VC to 2nd VC.

any idea?

Comment: as per your code, you are pushing to second VC, after finishing the data process, so there is no use in using activity indicator as it will never be showing in this case. Either show the secondVC and then load the data through a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try GCD:

```
// instantiate the activity indicator
UIActivityIndicatorView  *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activity.center = self.view.center; 

// start your activity indicator
[activity startAnimating]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // load data on background thread
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:lblName.text forKey:@"lblname"];
    //........Lots of Data........(then in the end of 1st VC)........//

    // update UI on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // stop your activity indicator
       [activity stopAnimating]

       RecievVC *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecievVC"];
       obj.dicData = dict;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:true];
    });
});
```

Comment: What didn’t work? Did you instantiate the activity indicator, e.g. in `viewDidLoad` of VC1? In my code I am assuming it is a `@property` of VC1.

Comment: I am wondering if your activity indicator is set up properly, which could be why you don't see it. See the edits in my answer.

Comment: these errors what I've got       *** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2d312b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010941af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Please show more of the error, this part is not very helpful in determining what could be happening. So now it is crashing, did that happen before as well? If so, please update your question.